# Error while integrating MillenialMedia mediation through AdMob

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I have adMob working perfectly (I am getting adMob test ads)and im trying to add MillennialMedia as another adSource. However, after following the instructions I get 31 warnings and most of them look like that

```
while processing /Users/Wagner/Documents/Xcode Projects/ProjectA/mm-ad-sdk-ios-6.1.0-222a9a3/mediation_adapters/ios-mm-admob-adapter-1.0.1-88fe579/libMMAdMobAdapter.a(MMAdMobAdapter.o):
warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/Wagner/Documents/Xcode Projects/ProjectA/mm-ad-sdk-ios-6.1.0-222a9a3/mediation_adapters/ios-mm-admob-adapter-1.0.1-88fe579/libMMAdMobAdapter.a(MMAdMobAdapter.o):
warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
(null): warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No such file or directory

(null): warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/Foundation-A3SOD99KJ0S9.pcm: No object file for requested architecture

(null): warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/GoogleMobileAds-3NBJJMJ6U9J0B.pcm: No such file or directory

(null): warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/GoogleMobileAds-3NBJJMJ6U9J0B.pcm: No object file for requested architecture

(null): warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No such file or directory

(null): warning: /Users/stramer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/IBN9JU271CTC/UIKit-2LM3EQU7VVY4O.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
```

and a much more similar ones. I already have Foundation.framework and all the other required framework linked. (except libxml2.dylib; everytime i add this xCode adds libxml2.2.dylib instead - Not sure if it matters?). I am not sure what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't found a solution for this yet the problem is because it's using the developer's from MM to compile here for Release. Just go to Targets > Build Settings > Build Options > Debug Information Format: and change the Release option from "DWARF with dSYM File" to just "DWARF" and you should be all set.